# The fedEx function should return a value of Payment Required if it is not passed a payment

Tags: javascript, function

I am very new to javascript and i can't seem to grasp my mind in functions, parameters and arguments.

I am trying to return a value of Payment Required if it is not passed a payment,  return a value of Payment Insufficient if it receives a payment of less than 1000, and if receives sufficient funds it will return a value of OK

```
    var fedEx = function(letters, boxes, payment){

        if (payments < 1){
            return "Payment Required";
        };
        else if (payments < 1000){
            return "Payment Insufficient";
        };
        else {
            return "OK";
        };

    };
```

this is all my codes

```
    var usps = function(letters, speed) {
        if (letters.length > 5){
            return fedEx(letters, null, 1000);
        };
    };

    var mailCarrier = function(letter) {

        usps([letter], "slow")

    };

    var fedEx = function(letters, boxes, payment){

        if (payments < 1){
            return "Payment Required";
        };
        else if (payments < 1000){
            return "Payment Insufficient";
        };
        else {
            return "OK";
        };

    };
```

i get this error "ReferenceError: fedEx is not defined"

Comment: Definte the fedEx variable before everything else. Also remove the semi colons between the if/else statements

Comment: Don't use the `var x = function() {...}` syntax. Use `function x() {...}` instead. I recommend a free online course like this: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript

Comment: Also, you have a parameter named `payment` (with no `s`) but you then test `if (payments <1000)` (with an `s`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were syntax errors in the fedEx function: removed semicolons after the conditional blocks, replaced payments with payment.

```js
function fedEx(letters, boxes, payment) {
  if (!payment) {
    return "Payment Required";
  } else if (payment < 1000) {
    return "Payment Insufficient";
  }
  return "OK";
};

console.log(fedEx(0,0,null))
console.log(fedEx(0,0,0))
console.log(fedEx(0,0,100))
console.log(fedEx(0,0,1001))
```

defining functions like this will allow you to ignore ordering...

```
function fedEx(...) {...}
```

instead of...

```
var fedEx = function(...) {...}
```

Comment: what should i put on "if" line if i wanted to return "Payment Required" if there's no payment recieved?

Comment: @PaoloMosca - see edit.  !payment captures a null payment as well as zero

Comment: Also, there's no need for the `else`s. If the code hits the following `if` it was because it was not returned on the previous one.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel - agreed.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel do i not need it if the person pays 1000? im kinda lost, sorry im really new at javascript :(

Comment: @PaoloMosca 1000 or more won't be caught by the conditions, so execution will "fall through" to the return.

Comment: @lara oh that makes sense now. thank you so much for your help!